# How to have a table with Foreign Key only in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables `RelImpOrdi` and `Imprimantes` defined in EF as follows :

```
public class RelImpOrdi
{
    [Key]
    public int IdImprimante { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string NomOrdinateur { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ImpDefault { get; set; }
}

public class Imprimantes
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string NomPartage { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that I need `RelImpOrdi` to have several identical `IdImprimante` entries, and since it is defined as a Primary Key, it creates some errors.  So how can I have `IdImprimante` as not unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that the very purpose of a Primary Key? It must be unique and must have a value.

So you can't set a primary key field as not unique.

And now for your problem, you can give RelImpOrdi its own primary key field which has its own unique value for each of its record.

You can use IdImprimante as a foreign key to the table Imprimantes.

This way you'll be able to maintain the unique identity of each record of RelImpOrdi and also store multiple records with different or same IdImprimante values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a one-to-many relationship not one-to-one.

add a int id for RelImpOrdi class, with [key] annotation.
remove the [key] annotation for  IdImprimante in RelImpOrdi class.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use One-To-Many relation ship. For this you must have a primary key column and a foreign key column. You have to use `[ForeignKey]` attribute for this.

Answer (score 0):

Primary Key has to be unique. Your options are:
1. Remove Primary Key from table.
2. Create other column for Primary Key let's say 'Id' then this property will have attribute [Key] and You will be able to have not unique IdImprimante. But then probably you will have to change your FK.

Comment: Option 1 can't work with Entity Framework since you need a primary key. Good idea in 2 I will try thanks